# Is the solution to the exercise of the book "Functions of one complex variable by John B. Conway " Of Chapter 7 (Riemann Mapping Theorem) correct?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, metric-spaces

> Let, $ G$ and $\Omega $ be two open sets in the plane and let $f:G \to\Omega$ be a continuous function which is one-one, onto be such that
> $f^{-1} : \Omega \to G$ is also continuous. Suppose $\{z_n\} $ is a
> sequence in $G$ which converges to a point $z \in \partial G$; also
> suppose $w=\lim f(z_n) $ exists. Prove that $w\in \partial \Omega$

This is an exercise of the book
"Functions of one complex variable by John B. Conway "
Of Chapter 7 (Riemann Mapping Theorem)

Strategy :(Proof by contradiction.)

Assume , $w=\lim f(z_n) \in \Omega$

$ f(z_n)\to w $ means $ w\in \overline {\Omega} $ and $\overline {\Omega}=int(\Omega )\cup \partial \Omega. $

Given $\Omega$ is open, so it contains no boundary points. $\Omega \cap \partial \Omega =\emptyset$, hence it is enough to show $ w$  doesn't belong to $\Omega $ to show $w \in \partial \Omega$

Now, I have to show $z\in G$ to contradict the hypothesis.

How to execute the above strategy to proof the exercise?

My attempt:(Proof by contradiction.)

Assume , $w=\lim f(z_n) \in \Omega$

Then, $f(z_n) \subset \Omega$ and $f(z_n) \to w $ in $\Omega$

Since, $f^{-1} : \Omega \to G$ is continuous, $$f^{-1} (f(z_n)) \to f^{-1} (w) $$

As $f$ is bijective, $$z_n \to f^{-1} (w) $$

By uniqueness of limit, $z=f^{-1}(w) \in G$

And  contradict that $z\in \partial G$

Hence, $w=\lim f(z_n) \in \partial \Omega$

Is my proof correct?

Is there any way to use Riemann Mapping Theorem to solve the above exercise?

Edit    : $\partial \Omega =bdd(\Omega) = {\overline{(\Omega)}\setminus int(\Omega)}$

Comment: Isn't $\partial\Omega$ the *boundary* of $\Omega$ (i.e. $\overline{\Omega}\setminus\text{Int}(\Omega)$, although for open $\Omega$ it boils down to $\overline{\Omega}\setminus\Omega$), rather than the *complement* of $\Omega$?

Comment: The Riemann mapping theorem is about holomorphic mappings of *simply-connected domains* to the unit disk. I may be missing something, but I don't see how that would help here.

Comment: So, how is $w\in\Omega$ the opposite of $w\in\partial\Omega$ (i.e. where is the contradiction)?

Comment: @StinkingBishop: At the risk of responding to a rhetoric question: The limit of a sequence $(f(z_n))$ in $\Omega$ is necessarily in $\overline \Omega = \Omega \cup \partial \Omega$.

Comment: @MartinR Maybe. I think for proofs at this level one should put details like that in the proof.

Comment: Sir, $f(z_n) \to w $ means $w\in\overline{\Omega} $ and $\overline{\Omega} =int(\Omega ) \cup \partial{\Omega}$. and given $\Omega $ is open, so it contains no boundary points. $\Omega \cap \partial \Omega =\emptyset$ hence it is enough to show $w$ doesn't belong to $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is all correct. It's best to inutitively think homeomorphism conserves limit. If $f(z_n)\rightarrow w$ in $\Omega$, then the corresponding limit holds in the domain $G$, hence $z_n$ converges in $G$ not just in $\overline{G}$. Formally, we apply $f^{-1}$ to the equality $\lim f(z_n)=w\in \Omega$.

This is an almost trivial fact compared to the Riemann Mapping Theorem. Also as pointed out in comments, $G$ or $\Omega$ are not necessarily simply connected, hence Riemann Mapping Thereom cannot be applied.

This is probably used to show a stronger version of Riemann Mapping Theorem, that is the version for simply connected domain with smooth boundaries.