# $|f|\leq |g|$ in each $r\mathbb{T}^2$ implies on $\mathbb{D}^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

> Question: Let $f,g\in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{D^2})$ (holomorphic functions on bidisc). Assume $|f|\leq|g|$ holds on each $r\mathbb{T}^2:=\{(z_1,z_2)\in \mathbb{D}^2: |z_1|=|z_2|=r\}$, $-\leq r<1$. And the zero set $Z(g)\subseteq Z(f)$. It is ture that $|f|\leq |g|$ on $\mathbb{D}^2$?

I try to put $h=f/g$ and use something like *Riemann's removable-singularity Theorem* or *maximal modular principal*. But I fails.

Comment: Edit: I also assume $Z(g)\subseteq Z(f)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not need the assumption $Z(g) \subseteq Z(f)$.

Let $w = (w_1,w_2) \in \mathbb{D}^2$. We want to show that $|f(w)| \leq |g(w)|$.

If $|w_1| = |w_2|$, then $w \in |w_1|\mathbb{T}^2$, and $|f(w)| \leq |g(w)|$ holds by hypothesis.

Thus, suppose $|w_1| \ne |w_2|$ and, wlog, $|w_1| < |w_2| =:r$.
Let $F(z) = f(z,w_2)$ and $G(z) = g(z,w_2)$ (functions of one complex variable).
For all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=r$, we have $(z,w_2) \in r\mathbb{T}^2$ and, hence, $|F(z)| \leq |G(z)|$.
By the maximum principle, it follows that $|F(z)| \leq |G(z)|$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z| \leq r$. In particular, this holds for $z=w_1$.

Comment: Sorry, Florian. As you write: "By the maximum principle, it follows that $|F(z)|\leq |G(z)|$ with $|z|\leq r$" why? For example $1\leq |z|$ on $|z|=1$, but this is not holds when $|z|<1$. So I think $Z(g)\subseteq Z(f)$, (even "counting multiple") is needed.

Comment: I was in the wrong as your simple counterexample shows. Would you be willing to add the hypothesis that $Z(g) \subseteq Z(f)$ with "counting multiples" as you put it? If you do, then $H(z) = F(z)/G(z)$ has removable singularities, $|H(z)| \leq 1$ on $\{|z|=r\}$ and, hence, by the maximum principle $|H(z)| \leq 1$ on $\{|z| \leq r\}$.

Answer (score -1):

Use Cauchy's formula to write the functions on $r\mathbb{D}^2$ in terms of the values on $r\mathbb{T}^2$.  Then compare the integrals.  See e.g. https://www.jirka.org/scv

Comment: Sir, please check the solution .It will be very helpful for me. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326439/is-my-solution-to-the-exercise-of-the-book-functions-of-one-complex-variable-by

Comment: Sorry, Professor. Can you be more specific? If we write $$f(rz)=(\frac{1}{2i\pi})^2\int_{\mathbb{T}^2}\frac{f(rw)}{w-z}dw.$$ so as $g$. Then $|f(rz)|\leq (\frac{1}{2\pi})^2\int_{\mathbb{T}^2}\frac{|f(rw)|}{|w-z|}|dw| \leq (\frac{1}{2\pi})^2\int_{\mathbb{T}^2}\frac{|g(rw)|}{|w-z|}|dw|$, since $|f_r|\leq |g_r|$ on $\mathbb{T}^2$. But can this deduce that $|f(rz)|\leq|g(rz)|$?